# Parsing Json file present in an xml tag into XML sepearte tags using XSLT 2.0

Tags: json, xml, parsing, xslt, xslt-2.0

Need help with xslt 2.0 to achieve below requirement.

- **Input**:

```
<code>"{
  "successful": true,
  "errors": [],
  "elements": [
    {
      "code": "1234567890",
      "channelProcessingTime": 15676456700
    },
    {
      "code": "0987654321",
      "channelProcessingTime": 36509878076
    }
  ]
}"</code>
```

- **Required output**:

```
<code>
    <successful>true</successful>
    <elements>
        <code>1234567890</code>
        <channelProcessingTime>15676456700</channelProcessingTime>
    </elements>
    <elements>
        <code>0987654321</code>
        <channelProcessingTime>36509878076</channelProcessingTime>
    </elements>
</code>
```

Need help with xslt 2.0 to achieve said requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot switch to a processor that supports XSLT 3.0 (where this would be much easier)?

Comment: Ok, I can. what would be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 3.0** this would be a trivial problem - but first you must remove the quotes surrounding your JSON code in order to get a valid JSON:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="code">
    <!-- remove surrounding quotes -->
    <xsl:variable name="json" select="replace(., '^&quot;|&quot;$', '')" />
    <code>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
    </code>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this can fail if a JSON name is not a valid XML element name.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But the product doesn't allow me to use 3.0 where I am required to implement the same.
Can you suggest a solution in 2.0 ?

Comment: You should have thought of that before you replied yes to my question and wasted my time.

Comment: sorry abt that, actually I was testing at local first and then tried at the product.